# Pushing data to cleardb Heroku via mysql workbench throwing error

Tags: mysql, heroku, mysql-workbench

ERROR 1044 (42000) at line 1: Access denied for user 'user_name_of_cleardb_at_heroku'@'%' to database 'i_am_uploading'

I dumped data from my localhost to a dump folder via mysql workbench. I'm uploading the same dump filer data to heroku. I'm getting this error. I made the server instance successfully ?

What exactly is the problem ? How can I debug ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says it clearly. The user user_name_of_cleardb_at_heroku does not have the rights to act on the db 'i_am_uploading'. So first grant rights to that user and then try again. Alternatively use a user with the proper rights. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/grant.html for the syntax of GRANT. You probably need something like:

```
grant all on i_am_uploading.* to user_name_of_cleardb_at_heroku@%;
```

You need to run this with a user who has rights to grant privileges.

Comment: It may seem weird but I think there are no user with rights to grant privileges on Heroku's cleardb.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku don't allow you to create a new database.

When creating tables don't forget to use the user name in front of the table name just like:

CREATE TABLE heroku_7036ce5029e34fc.usuarios(
user_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
user_first_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
user_last_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
user_email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
user_password VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
user_phone VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ( user_id )
);

if you are using a script try to include the user name in every statement.